# How to use the start command properly here?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

```
C:\>start iexplorer.exe /low
The system cannot find the file iexplorer.exe.
```

How would I properly type this so when using the start that iexplorer while setting the title to 'MyBrowser' and to set it at low priority I would use /low and for minimized as well /min right?

Comment: Which version of windows, and is iexplorer in your path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting that error is because the Internet Explorer .exe  is actually named `iexplore.exe`, not `iexplorer.exe`. It's just an extra `r` that you typed in its name that shouldn't be there.

The full command for what you're trying to do should be:

```
C:\>start "MyBrowser" /low /min iexplore.exe
```